# HTML5 tag to use for a group of thumbnail images

Tags: html, semantics

I'm curious what tag would make the most semantic sense to encapsulate a group of thumbnail images? Does it make sense to use the `<figure>` tag (reading the html5 spec, it's not clear)? Or stick with a `<div>`, or is it considered it's own `<section>`?

Normally I'd probably use a div to section it off, but trying to utilize the semantic structure of html5, I was hoping maybe there would be a tag that fits this sort of content better.

Thoughts? Suggestions? All are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Depends on your layout. Is it a section of your layout (an integral part) , or is it more of a sub-section (more of a supporting/make it look pretty part). Also do you have other content in it apart from thumbnails?

Comment: Agreed on Petah's comment - we have to have more context to be able to speak to which tags make the most sense semantically.

Comment: @Petah - it only contains thumbs. I would consider it more of a sub-section than it's own major section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a semantic point of view, using `<figure>` is probably the best fit.  If you check [the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-figure-element), you'll see that it's perfectly acceptable to include a series of images within a single `<figure>` declaration.

Example:

```
<figure>
 <img src="castle1423.jpeg" title="Etching. Anonymous, ca. 1423."
      alt="The castle has one tower, and a tall wall around it.">
 <img src="castle1858.jpeg" title="Oil-based paint on canvas. Maria Towle, 1858."
      alt="The castle now has two towers and two walls.">
 <img src="castle1999.jpeg" title="Film photograph. Peter Jankle, 1999."
      alt="The castle lies in ruins, the original tower all that remains in one piece.">
 <figcaption>The castle through the ages: 1423, 1858, and 1999 respectively.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

There is also [a similar example](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) shown on [HTML5Doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com) where multiple images (which could just as easily be thumbnails) are listed as children of a single `<figure>` element.

Comment: What if the thumbs are laid out as a list, `<ul>`, of images, instead of direct children like in your example?

Comment: Putting them in a list wouldn't matter. As long as they're related to the main content, a figure would be appropriate. If the pictures could be removed and have no impact on the content, then semantically they're not really related to the main content and probably shouldn't be in a figure.